# Parentheses placement and identifying redexes in a lambda expression

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, lambda-calculus

I'm struggling to understand how to identify redexes in a lambda expression. 
I've been given the following expression and asked to identify all redexes

(.(.))(.)

I understand that -terms are left associative. So I believe I would place my parentheses as follows

(((.((.)))(.)))

I see that (.(.))(.) is a redex as it follows a (.)' pattern and I believe (.) is also a redex. Is there a third that spans the entire expression?

Would the reduction look something like this?

(((.((0.0)))(1.1))2)

(((0.0)(1.1))2)

((1.1)2)

2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the $\lambda$-term 
\begin{align}
(\lambda x. (\lambda x_0.x_0) x)(\lambda x_1. x_1) x
\end{align}
there are exactly two redexes: $(\lambda x. (\lambda x_0.x_0) x)(\lambda x_1. x_1)$ and $(\lambda x_0.x_0) x$.

Your reduction is correct, it starts by reducing the redex $(\lambda x. (\lambda x_0.x_0) x)(\lambda x_1. x_1)$.

Note that another reduction is possible, starting by reducing the redex $(\lambda x_0.x_0) x$:
\begin{align}
&(\lambda x. (\lambda x_0.x_0) x)(\lambda x_1. x_1) x_2
\\
&(\lambda x. x)(\lambda x_1. x_1) x_2
\\
&(\lambda x_1. x_1) x_2
\\
&x_2
\end{align} 
Coincidentally, the two reductions are extensionally the same (the same $\lambda$-terms), even though they are obtained intensionally in a different way, by reducing different redexes.